# asynchronous operation still pending

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a service to get all my boxes from the database like this :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetBoxes/")]
[ResponseType(typeof(ResultQuery))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBoxes()
{
    try
    {
        var boxes = db.Boxes.ToList<Box>();
        foreach (Box in boxes)
        {
            status.Add(GetBox(box));
        }
        return Ok(ConvertToResultQuery(boxes));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return InternalServerError(e);
    }
}

public GenericBox GetBox(Box box)
{
    try
    {
        //Do a lot of stuff with the database
        return genericBox;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static ResultQuery ConvertToResultQuery(object result)
{
    return new ResultQuery(result);
}
```

Where ResultQuery has just one object attribute containing the result of my service.

The service is simple but for some reason it gives me this error when I try it in postman :

**An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.**

VisualStudio also gives me a warning advising to use await but I don't understand where I should put it.

Comment: GetBox should be asynchronous. Pretty certain it is Public async Task GenericBox GetBox(Box box){ }. Here is a sample page https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/23/async-actions-in-aspnet-mvc-4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetBoxes` method is an async method, but your `GetBox` is not.

You say that you are doing db work inside the `GetBox` method but everything in that method is running synchronously.  Consider changing the signature of `GetBox` to:

```
public async Task<GenericBox> GetBox(Box box)
{
    try
    {
        //Do a lot of stuff with the database
        //'await' database calls here
        return genericBox;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }        
}
```

Then in your `GetBoxes` method change your foreach to a Task.WhenAll() instead:

```
var result = await Task.WhenAll(boxes.Select(x => GetBox(x)));
```

The `result` variable will be a Task

If you do not want to mess with `Task.WhenAll()`, you can simply `await` the `GetBox` method inside your loop:

```
status.Add(await GetBox(box));
```

Comment: Thank you ! Should I also use async in the first ToList call ? "var boxes = db.Boxes.ToList<Box>();"

Comment: Use async methods whenever possible. If you are using EF and `ToListAsync` is available to you then yes you should use and await that as well.

Comment: Everything builds now but I still get the exception when I try the service with postman.

Comment: Post your updated code in your OP so we can take a look